# Trying to make a DEX

Tags: solidity, javascript, uniswap, decentralized-exchange

I am currently trying to make a "uniswap clone" in the sense that you can swap ERC-20 token pairs. I've already created a smart contract that allows ETH to be sent, but want to add an ERC-20 token swap functionality.

Do you guys have any tips/tricks and the best places to go such as github repo's or YouTube videos to help myself build something like this.

Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: I recommend watching [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/XOvtnDx1m5c) on how to make a dex

Comment: You should read the original Uniswap whitepaper.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the github of Uniswap https://github.com/orgs/Uniswap/repositories?type=all

Find all the repo relating to Uniswap v2 and start playing around with their smart contract tests. Get a feel around the repos.

This tutorial on ethereum tutorials have helped me tons with understanding the uniswap smart contracts function by function.
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/uniswap-v2-annotated-code/

And ofc i can't forget to mention about the youtube channel "Smart Contract Programmer". His videos about uniswap v2 is goldmine and he already started his videos about explaining the math behind Uniswap V3
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJWh7F3AFyQ_x01VKzr9eyA/search?query=Uniswap%20v2

Also this medium post about deploying Uniswap V2 Smart Contracts was really helpful too
https://medium.com/@maxime.atton/fork-uniswap-v2-smart-contracts-ui-on-remix-e885d6cea176

I advice checking out all the resources available around Uniswap V2 then when u feel comfortable , try using the smart contract and deploying them. Make a prototype ✨

Answer (score 0):

Try this guthub repo, it's a fork of pancakeswap which in turn is inherited from uniswap.
https://github.com/goosedefi/goose-frontend-amm